# Weird Routing Behavior in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using rails 4.2.  I have created a form that submits to a particular action in my controller.  Here is the beginning of the form code and the controller definition:

**view.html.erb**

```
<div id="account-booking" class="tab-pane">
  <%= form_for @booking_info, url: { action: 'book' } do |b| %>
      <fieldset class="group column-1">
        <legend>Booking Preference for <%= Rails.configuration.x.app_settings.year %></legend>

        <div class="group column-full radio-list">
          <%= label_tag('Select Room Type') %>
          <% @available_rooms.each do |rt| %>
              <div class="radio-item">
                <!--
                <%= b.radio_button :room_type_id, rt.id, :class => 'rb_room_type inline', :onclick => fetch_room_info_path(:id => rt.id), :remote => true %>
                <%= b.radio_button :room_type_id, rt.id, :class => 'rb_room_type inline', :onclick => 'render_room_info('+ rt.id.to_s + ');' %>
                -->
                <%= b.radio_button :room_type_id, rt.id, :class => 'rb_room_type inline' %>
                <%= content_tag :span, rt.name  %>
                <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="<%= rt.description %>">
                  <%= image_tag "tooltip.png", :class=>"tooltip-icon" %>
                </a>
              </div>
          <% end %>

          <%= b.label :roommate_preference, 'Roommate Preference' %>
          <%= b.text_area :roommate_preference, :class => 'form-control' %>

          <div class="account-checkbox-options">
            <%= b.label :is_flexible, class: 'checkbox inline' do %>
                <%= b.check_box :is_flexible %>
                I am flexible with regards to my room choice.
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--
        <div id="estimated-due" class="group column-2">

        </div>
        -->
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="group column-2 account-preferences">
        <legend>Your Room Information for <%= Rails.configuration.x.app_settings.year %></legend>
        <div class="group column-1">
          <div class="group column-full add-tabbing">
            <%= label_tag('Selected Room:') %>
            <span><%= @booking_info.room_type.blank? ? '<No Room Selected>' : @booking_info.room_type.name  %></span>
          </div>

          <div class="group column-full add-tabbing">
            <%= label_tag('Assigned Room:') %>
            <span><%= @booking_info.assigned_type.blank? ? '<No Room Assigned>' : @booking_info.assigned_type.name  %></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group column-2">
          <div class="group column-full add-tabbing">
            <%= label_tag('Total Due:') %>
            <span ><%= number_to_currency(@booking_info.total_due.blank? ? 0.00 : @booking_info.total_due) %></span>
          </div>
          <div class="group column-full add-tabbing">
            <%= label_tag('Current Balance:') %>
            <span><%= number_to_currency(@booking_info.outstanding_balance.blank? ? 0.00 : @booking_info.outstanding_balance) %></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <% unless @booking_info.assigned_type.blank? %>
            <div class="group column-full">
              <h2>Assigned Room Information</h2>
            </div>
        <% end %>
      </fieldset>

      <div class="account-buttons">
        <%= b.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
        <%= link_to 'Cancel', '/pages/home', class: 'link-button-cancel' %>
      </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

**account_controller.rb**

```
def book
    @booking = PersonRoom.new(booking_params)
    @requested_room = RoomType.find(params[:person_room][:room_type_id])
    @booking.room_type = @requested_room

    if update_booking @booking
      redirect_to :controller => 'account', :action => 'view'
    else
      render('view')
    end
 end
```

All of this works beautifully when there is no PersonRoom record (e.g. if I'm doing an insert).  However, if I try to update the record, using the same exact form / action (because both the view and the action are exactly the same regardless of whether i'm inserting or updating), I get an error when I click "Submit":

No route matches [PATCH] "/account/book"

This makes no sense.  I'm on the exact same page.  I just used all of this code to create the record, so the route clearly exists (because it calls /account/book). Now I want to update but suddenly the route doesn't match? And it never even breaks into the code because it doesn't call the controller action.  This makes zero sense to me.  Hope someone can help.

Comment: Are you providing the ID along with the request when you go to update the entity?

Comment: what does your routes.rb file look like? The update does not work because of the type of request (PATCH), probably not because of anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I winced when looking over your code, here's how I'd have done it:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :rooms do
   resources :bookings #-> url.com/rooms/:room_id/bookings/new
end

#app/controllers/bookings_controller.rb
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_room
   def new
      @booking = room.bookings.new
   end

   def create
      @booking = room.bookings.new booking_params
      @booking.save
   end

   def update
      @booking = room.bookings.update booking_params
   end

   private

   def set_room
      @room = Room.find params[:room_id]
   end

   def booking_params
      params.require(:booking).permit(:x, :y, :z)
   end
end
```

This setup is pretty standard with Rails (IE [resourceful routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web)):

> Browsers request pages from Rails by making a request for a URL using
>   a specific HTTP method, such as GET, POST, PATCH, PUT and DELETE. Each
>   method is a request to perform an operation on the resource. A
>   resource route maps a number of related requests to actions in a
>   single controller.

Observing this principle would likely resolve your "weird" routing errors due to their cohesion with the other aspects of the Rails system.

For example:

```
#app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
   #-> this shouldn't have a "book" action unless necessary. Your case is not necessary
end
```

--

The problem you have is that you're not adhering to the Rails' convention of keeping your system object-orientated.

The importance of this is huge; Rails is designed to make it as simple as possible to [CRUD (create read update destroy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) data objects. These objects are built from database data in the "models":

[image]

I use this picture a lot - it shows how Rails should work. You build objects in your `Models` which you manipulate in your controllers. The views show it all to the user.

Thus, when you're looking at your code, I would keep it as simple as possible:

```
#app/models/room.rb
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :bookings
   has_many :users, through: :bookings
   belongs_to :type
end

#app/models/booking.rb
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :room
   belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :bookings
   has_many :rooms, through: :bookings
end
```

This will allow you to call the following:

```
@room = Room.find 1
@room.bookings #-> collection of bookings per room
```

You could also do something like the following (simple) for the views:

```
#app/views/bookings/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @booking do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :x %>
   <%= f.text_field :y %>
   <%= f.text_field :z %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: So I get what you are saying.  But even if I organised it this way, would it work without the changes I made to the route.config? The underlying problem was that the route was only configured to look for get and post verbs and this call was using a patch verb so the route wasn't configured.  Wouldn't I still have to add the code in my answer to the route.config even if i reorganised the controllers as you suggest?

Comment: If you just wanted to make it work with `put/patch`, you'd use the `via` attribute to define them. The problem is deeper than that, though; as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I understand its deeper than that :) I just wasn't sure if I would get the same error if I reorganised everything as you suggested or if the reorganisation would just cause everything to work because of the way Rails is designed. In other MVC frameworks I've worked with, you typically need to be explicit in your route creation.

Comment: hehehe Yes this is why I was trying to explain about the "Rails" paradigm - many people coming from other MVC frameworks don't get how simple Rails has been created. It's kind of like socialism, it works if you want to be conventional, if you do your own thing, you have to understand the system to keep it succinct.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  It was something really stupid.  I had the following line in my route.config:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]
```

I just needed to change this to:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post, :patch, :put, :delete]
```

Now it handles updates (i.e. patch / put)

Comment: This code is not really that good - let me write an answer to give you some ideas